# PIC24F UART half-duplex communication protocol

Tags: c, uart, microchip

I’m actually trying to establish a half-duplex UART communication protocol between my PIC24F MCU and PC. The goal is to be able to send a message like “Hello” from the MCU and get the response “Hello there” from the PC and vice versa.

With my actual code I’m able to send something to PC from the MCU but I still cannot get any response from it …
I’ve written an interrupt to deal with the receiver, but it seems that my code never goes into that interrupt. I’ve tested all the output pins of the adapter with an oscilloscope. Baudrate and clock seems to be also fine so the problem should by in the code.

Material used:

- PIC24F Curiosity Development Board
- Adafruit USB-TTL uart adapter
- MPLAB with x16 compiler
- Programming Language: C

Below you'll find my code if you wish to take a look on. Thank you for you attention.

```
/* THIS IS THE UART_TestingNEW
 *  
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: Pavel
 *
 * Created on 21 June 2021, 16:26
 */

/*
 * https://github.com/dsoze1138/24FJ128GA204_DM240004
 *
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: dan1138
 * Target: PIC24FJ128GA204
 * Compiler: XC16 v1.60
 * IDE: MPLABX v5.45
 *
 * Created on November 24, 2020, 12:02 PM
 *
 *                                                           PIC24FJ128GA204
 *               +----------------+               +--------------+                +-----------+                +--------------+
 * J4_MOSI <>  1 : RB9/RP9        :    LED2 <> 12 : RA10         :   J4_SDA <> 23 : RB2/RP2   : X2-32KHZ <> 34 : RA4/SOSCO    :
 *  RGB_G  <>  2 : RC6/RP22       :         <> 13 : RA7          :   J4_SCL <> 24 : RB3/RP3   :     LED1 <> 35 : RA9          :
 *  RGB_B  <>  3 : RC7/RP23       :         <> 14 : RB14/RP14    :      POT <> 25 : RC0/RP16  :    J4_CS <> 36 : RC3/RP19     :
 *     S2  <>  4 : RC8/RP24       :         <> 15 : RB15/RP15    :          <> 26 : RC1/RP17  :   J4_SCK <> 37 : RC4/RP20     :
 *     S1  <>  5 : RC9/RP25       :     GND -> 16 : AVSS         :          <> 27 : RC2/RP18  :    RGB_R <> 38 : RC5/RP21     :
 *    3v3  <>  6 : VBAT           :     3v3 -> 17 : AVDD         :      3v3 -> 28 : VDD       :      GND -> 39 : VSS          :
 *   10uF  ->  7 : VCAP           : ICD_VPP -> 18 : MCLR         :      GND -> 29 : VSS       :      3v3 -> 40 : VDD          :
 *         <>  8 : RB10/RP11/PGD2 :   J4_AN <> 19 : RA0/AN0      :          <> 30 : RA2/OSCI  :    J4_RX <> 41 : RB5/RP5/PGD3 :
 *         <>  9 : RB11/RP11/PGC2 :  J4_RST <> 20 : RA1/AN1      :          <> 31 : RA3/OSCO  :    J4_TX <> 42 : RB6/RP6/PGC3 :
 *         <> 10 : RB12/RP12      : ICD_PGD <> 21 : RB0/RP0/PGD1 :          <> 32 : RA8       :          <> 43 : RB7/RP7      :
 *         <> 11 : RB13/RP13      : ICD_PGC <> 22 : RB1/RP1/PGC1 : X2-32KHZ <> 33 : RB4/SOSCI :  J4_MISO <> 44 : RB8/RP8      :
 *               +----------------+               +--------------+                +-----------+                +--------------+
 *                                                              TQFP-44
 * 
 * Description:
 * 
 * Bare metal initialization of the DM240004 Curiosity Board
 * 
 * Setup the system oscillator for 32MHz using the internal FRC and the 4x PLL.
 * Turn on the 32.768KHz secondary oscillator.
 * Use UART1 and printf to send a message as 9600 baud.
 * Flash LED2 on for 500 milliseconds then off for 500 milliseconds.
 * 
 */

/*
 * Defines for system oscillator frequency.
 * Make sure that the PIC initialization selects this frequency.
 */
//#define FSYS (32000000ul)
//#define FCY  (FSYS/2ul)

#define FCY 10000000UL
/*
 * Target specific Special Function Register definitions
 */


// PIC24FJ128GA204 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG4
//#pragma config DSWDTPS = DSWDTPS1F      // Deep Sleep Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:68719476736 (25.7 Days))
//#pragma config DSWDTOSC = LPRC          // DSWDT Reference Clock Select (DSWDT uses LPRC as reference clock)
//#pragma config DSBOREN = ON             // Deep Sleep BOR Enable bit (DSBOR Enabled)
//#pragma config DSWDTEN = ON             // Deep Sleep Watchdog Timer Enable (DSWDT Enabled)
//#pragma config DSSWEN = ON              // DSEN Bit Enable (Deep Sleep is controlled by the register bit DSEN)
//#pragma config PLLDIV = DISABLED        // USB 96 MHz PLL Prescaler Select bits (PLL Disabled)
//#pragma config I2C1SEL = DISABLE        // Alternate I2C1 enable bit (I2C1 uses SCL1 and SDA1 pins)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = ON             // PPS IOLOCK Set Only Once Enable bit (Once set, the IOLOCK bit cannot be cleared)

// CONFIG3
#pragma config WPFP = WPFP127         // Write Protection Flash Page Segment Boundary (Page 127 (0x1FC00))
//#pragma config SOSCSEL = ON             // SOSC Selection bits (SOSC circuit selected)
//#pragma config WDTWIN = PS25_0          // Window Mode Watchdog Timer Window Width Select (Watch Dog Timer Window Width is 25 percent)
//#pragma config PLLSS = PLL_PRI          // PLL Secondary Selection Configuration bit (PLL is fed by the Primary oscillator)
//#pragma config BOREN = ON               // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset Enable)
#pragma config WPDIS = WPDIS            // Segment Write Protection Disable (Disabled)
#pragma config WPCFG = WPCFGDIS         // Write Protect Configuration Page Select (Disabled)
#pragma config WPEND = WPENDMEM         // Segment Write Protection End Page Select (Write Protect from WPFP to the last page of memory)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config POSCMD = XT              // Primary Oscillator Select (XT Oscillator Enabled)
//#pragma config WDTCLK = LPRC            // WDT Clock Source Select bits (WDT uses LPRC)
#pragma config OSCIOFCN = OFF           // OSCO Pin Configuration (OSCO/CLKO/RA3 functions as CLKO (FOSC/2))
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD           // Clock Switching and Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Configuration bits (Clock switching and Fail-Safe Clock Monitor are disabled)
#pragma config FNOSC = PRI              // Initial Oscillator Select (Primary Oscillator (XT, HS, EC))
//#pragma config ALTCMPI = CxINC_RB       // Alternate Comparator Input bit (C1INC is on RB13, C2INC is on RB9 and C3INC is on RA0)
//#pragma config WDTCMX = WDTCLK          // WDT Clock Source Select bits (WDT clock source is determined by the WDTCLK Configuration bits)
#pragma config IESO = ON                // Internal External Switchover (Enabled)

// CONFIG1
#pragma config WDTPS = PS32768          // Watchdog Timer Postscaler Select (1:32,768)
#pragma config FWPSA = PR128            // WDT Prescaler Ratio Select (1:128)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Windowed WDT Disable (Standard Watchdog Timer)
#pragma config FWDTEN = ON              // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT enabled in hardware)
#pragma config ICS = PGx1               // Emulator Pin Placement Select bits (Emulator functions are shared with PGEC1/PGED1)
//#pragma config LPCFG = OFF              // Low power regulator control (Disabled - regardless of RETEN)
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Segment Write Protect (Write to program memory allowed)
#pragma config GCP = OFF                // General Segment Code Protect (Code protection is disabled)
#pragma config JTAGEN = ON              // JTAG Port Enable (Enabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
/*
 * Standard header files
 */
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libpic30.h>
#include "xc.h"
/*
 * Initialize this PIC
 */
    char uart1_buffer[50];
    int uart_index;
// uart init funtion 
 
void UART1Init(void)
{
    U1BRG = 25;     // 9600 @ 8MHZ
//    U1BRG = 32;     // 9600 @ 10MHZ
    
    U2STA = 0110; 
    U1MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;      // UART2 is Enabled
     
    U1MODEbits.USIDL = 0;       // Continue operation at Idlestate
    U1MODEbits.IREN = 0;        // IrDA En/Decoder is disabled
    U1MODEbits.RTSMD = 0;       // flow control mode
    U1MODEbits.UEN1 = 0b00;     // UTX, RTX, are enabled U1CTS, U1RTS are disabled
    U1MODEbits.UEN0 = 0b00;     // UTX, RTX, are enabled U1CTS, U1RTS are disabled
    U1MODEbits.WAKE = 1;        // Wake-up on start bit is enabled
    U1MODEbits.LPBACK = 0;      // Loop-back is disabled
    U1MODEbits.ABAUD = 0;       // auto baud is disabled
    U1MODEbits.RXINV = 0;       // No RX inversion
    U1MODEbits.BRGH = 0;        // low boud rate
    U1MODEbits.PDSEL = 0b00;    // 8bit no parity
    U1MODEbits.STSEL = 0;       // one stop bit 
 
    U1STAbits.UTXISEL0 = 1; // transmit interrupt occurs when all bytes are transmitted
    U1STAbits.UTXISEL1 = 0b00;      
    U1STA &= 0xDFFF;            // clear TXINV by bit masking
    U1STAbits.UTXBRK = 0;      // sync break tx is disabled
    U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1;        //transmit  is enabled
    U1STAbits.URXEN = 1;        // receive is enabled
    U1STAbits.URXISEL = 0b00;   // interrupt flag bit is set when RXBUF is filled whith 1 character
    U1STAbits.ADDEN = 0;        // address detect mode is disabled
    U1STAbits.RIDLE = 0;
 
    IPC2bits.U1RXIP = 0;        // sET uart1 Priority to 7
    IFS0bits.U1RXIF = 0;        // clear interrupt flag of rx
    IFS0bits.U1TXIF = 0;        // clear interrupt flag of rx
    IEC0bits.U1RXIE = 1;        // enable rx recieved data interrupt
    IEC0bits.U1TXIE = 0;
}
 
// uart transmit function 
 
void UART1TransmitByte(char tx_byte)
{
    U1TXREG = tx_byte;
    while(!(U1STAbits.TRMT))
    {
    }
}
 
 
// uart read string function
 
 
void UART1TransmitString(char *tx_str)
{
    char ch;
    while(*tx_str != 0x00)
    {
        ch = *tx_str;
        U1TXREG = ch;
        while(!(U1STAbits.TRMT))
        {
        }
        tx_str++;
    }
}
 
//void UART_Receiver(uint8_t *c, bool *rx_flag)
//{
//    if (U1STAbits.FERR){
//        uint8_t er = U1RXREG;
//    }
//    else if (U1STAbits.OERR)
//    {
//        U1STAbits.URXEN = 0; 
//        U1STAbits.URXEN = 1; 
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        *c = U1RXREG; //red the receiver buffer
//        *rx_flag = true;
//    }
//}

 
 
void __attribute__((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _U1RXInterrupt()
{
    char ch;
    _U1RXIF = 0;    //Clear RX interrupt flag
    ch = U1RXREG;
     
    uart1_buffer[uart_index++]=ch;
     
    if(uart_index>100)uart_index=0;
     
     
}


//void __attribute__ ((interrupt, auto_psv))  _U1RXInterrupt(void)
//{
//    if (U2STAbits.OERR == SET)
//        U2STABITS.OERR = CLEAR;
//}
 
int main(void) {
     
     
    // uart pin selection 
    OSCCON = 0x0000;
    OSCTUN = 0x0000;
    CLKDIV = 0x0000;
    //resetSource = RCON;
    RCON = 0x00;
    INTCON1bits.NSTDIS = 1;
//    AD1PCFGL = 0xFF; 
    ANSA = 0;
    ANSB = 0;
    ANSC = 0;
    
    RPINR18bits.U1RXR = 6; // Assign U1RXR to RP6
    _TRISB6 = 1; //CONFIGURE PIN TO I/P
    RPOR3bits.RP7R = 3; //Assign U1TX To Pin RP7
    _TRISB7 = 0; //CONFIGURE PIN TO O/P
//    _LATB7 = 1;
     
      
       
    //uart_index=0;
    CNPU1bits.CN9PUE = 1;
     
    UART1Init();
        UART1TransmitString("Transmission OK\r\n");
//        UART1ReceiveString("Receiving ok"); 
        __delay_ms(500);
    while(1)
    {
        if (uart1_buffer == 'A')
        {
           UART1TransmitString("Receiving OK\r\n");
        }
     
       if(uart_index>0)
       {
           UART1TransmitString(uart1_buffer);
//           __delay_ms(500);
           uart_index = 0;
           memset(uart1_buffer,'\0',sizeof(uart1_buffer));
           
          
//           UART1TransmitString("Receiving ok"); 
       }
    }
     
    /// transmission completed 
     
     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C not C#.

Comment: As for "my interrupt isn't working", the number one  thing to check as always: did you add it to the interrupt vector table? I've never used this part but upon Reading the Friendly Manual, it reveals that PIC24 uses a vector table (like most micros).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've never heard of this vector table, I'll take a look at it ! I was just setting the highest priority flag for the interrupt and that's all.

Comment: It's very fundamental stuff, so I'd recommend to check out some learning material about embedded systems programming before proceeding. Writing interrupts is _hard_, in my experience the vast majority of all programmers fail to implement them correctly. There's compiler optimizations, flag clearing, re-entrancy, specialized keywords, keeping the code small etc etc.

Comment: "half-duplex UART " and "cannot get any response from it " --> sounds like the receiver still might be driving.